# UIPopoverController - How to point to a position on UICollectionView cell's customised Accessory icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I 'm stuck with a problem...

I have a View, that uses UICollectionView and I am using number of images to display. On each of  cell Image's right top I am displaying a small Icon, Which will have UITapGestureRecognizer on it(Small icon). Whenever user taps on small I have to show a  UIPopoverController with nib file which is another class file with .h, .m and xib file. The problem is I cannot pin-point UIPopoverController on any(which small image I click on.), Instead what happens is that when ever I clicking on any of small icon image UITapGestureRecognizer always points to the first cell's small Image...

May anyone tell me what should I do to point UIPopoverController over on small image that I click on, please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (void)didRecognizeTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];

       // Do some workaround with the POINT to achieve your task

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that a `UITapGestureRecognizer` was attached to each icon, you could use that gesture recognizer's `view` property to display the popover:

```
- (void)didTapCellIcon:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *iconView = gesture.view;
    // Create myContentViewController and setup
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myContentViewController];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:iconView.bounds
                                       inView:iconView 
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
}
```